# Oracle Database Snapshot?

Tags: oracle, snapshot

Is there a proper snapshot function or anything analogue to it on Oracle Database (19c, 21c) on a schema or PDB level?

For example, I wanted to run some tests that will alter tables, procedures and update data from a schema. After finishing my tests I wanted to revert it to the state it was before I started changing it.
I'm used to do Virtual Machine snapshots, but I'm new to Oracle DB and was looking for something similar to it.

Is there anything like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to restore just the one schema you are testing, or the *entire* database instance (all schemas, including SYS)?

Answer (score 0):

[Using Flashback Database and Restore Points](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/using-flasback-database-restore-points.html)

> Oracle Flashback Database and restore points are related data
> protection features that enable you to rewind data back in time to
> correct any problems caused by logical data corruption or user errors
> within a designated time window.
>
> These features provide a more efficient alternative to point-in-time
> recovery and does not require a backup of the database to be restored
> first. The effects are similar to database point-in-time recovery
> (DBPITR). Flashback Database and restore points are not only effective
> in traditional database recovery situations but can also be useful
> during database upgrades, application deployments and testing
> scenarios when test databases must be quickly created and re-created.

Steps to implement:

1. Configure FRA to store flashback logs, have ARCHIVELOG mode enabled
2. Create guaranteed restore point(s):

`create restore point before_test guarantee flashback database;`

3. Do your tests.
4. Rewind (flashback) the database:

> ```
> shutdown immediate
> startup mount
> flashback database to restore point before_test;
> alter database open resetlogs;
> ```

5. Drop restore point if needed: `drop restore point before_test;`
6. Repeat from step 2.

Comment: @Daichi42 Note that this works if the objective is to rollback the entire database instance and not just a single schema. If the requirement is to only restore a single schema because there is ongoing work in others that can't be rolled back, then an export/import backup and recovery at the schema level using DataPump would be recommended.